# How to make custom pagination in swiper.js

Tags: javascript, swiper.js

Ok, so, i want to make a custom pagination in swiper.js, i don`t really know how to do right, please be lenient xD

/***** what i`ve tried to do ********/

/********* HTML CODE *********/

```
<div class="swiper">
                <div class="swiper-wrapper">
                    <div class="swiper-slide" data-swiper-autoplay="2000"><img src="../../images/services__first-slide.png" alt="slide"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="../../images/services__second-slide.png" alt="slide"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="../../images/services__third-slide.png" alt="slide"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="../../images/services__fourth-slide.png" alt="slide"></div>
                    <div class="swiper-slide"><img src="../../images/services__fifth-slide.png" alt="slide"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
        </div>
```

/********** javascript code **********/

/***** Initialising swiper ******

```
const swiper = new Swiper('.swiper', {
  loop: true,
  speed: 2000,
  autoplay: {
    delay: 2000
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    type: 'custom',
    clickable: true,
    renderCustom: function() {
      let activeIndex = swiper.realIndex
      let paginationCustom = document.querySelectorAll('.swiper-pagination-custom')
      for(let i = 0; i < paginationCustom.length; i++) {
        if(i === activeIndex) {
          paginationCustom[i].classList.add('swiper-pagination-custom-active')
        } else {
          paginationCustom[i].classList.remove('swiper-pagination-custom-active')
        }
        paginationCustom[i].innerHTML = menu[i]
      }
    }
  },
  modules: [Navigation, Pagination]
})
```

/**** paggination items ******/

```
let menu = [
'<div class="services__pagination-block"> <img src="../images/services-pagination__first-item.svg"> <p class="services__pagination-title">Complex design-project</p></div>',

'<div class="services__pagination-block"> <img src="../images/services-pagination__second-item.svg"> <p class="services__pagination-title">Planning solution</p></div>',

'<div class="services__pagination-block"> <img src="../images/services-pagination__third-item.svg"> <p class="services__pagination-title">Author supervision</p></div>',

'<div class="services__pagination-block"> <img src="../images/services-pagination__fourth-item.svg"> <p class="services__pagination-title">Repair and decoration</p></div>',

'<div class="services__pagination-block"> <img src="../images/services-pagination__fifth-item.svg"> <p class="services__pagination-title">Express-design</p></div>'
```